# NLTK tagging Proper Nouns as Adjectives after Web Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

Context:  I am scraping the front page of google news to find all the commonly occurring proper noun bigrams (names and organizations).  I filter out some of the irrelevant bigrams by filtering by frequency of bigram and capitalization.  However, nltk is incorrectly tagging many proper nouns as adjectives and I am not sure why.  Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
wikis = ["https://news.google.com/"]
for wiki in wikis:
    website = requests.get(wiki)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "lxml")
    text = ''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda     tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)])
    new =  re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z \n]','',text)

words = nltk.word_tokenize(new)
finder = nltk.bigrams(words)
dist = nltk.FreqDist(finder)
parse = [[" ".join(k),v] for k,v in dist.items()]
createcolumns = pd.DataFrame(parse, columns=['Bigrams','Frequency'])
webbigrams = createcolumns[createcolumns['Frequency'] >= 3]
x = webbigrams['Bigrams']
y = [s for s in x if all(x[0].isupper() for x in s.split())]
tags = nltk.pos_tag(y)
res = nltk.ne_chunk(tags)
print(res)
```

Sample of Incorrect Outputs:

```
Jennifer Westfeldt/JJ
New England/NN
US Open/JJ
Tom Brady/JJ
York Times/NNS
Stephen Colbert/JJ
Pittsburgh Steelers/NNS
Queen Elizabeth/JJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [spaCy](http://spacy.io/blog/dead-code-should-be-buried/). In [This post](http://spacy.io/blog/part-of-speech-POS-tagger-in-python/), he compares some POS accuracy too.